# How to get the number of documents in Elastic Search with Elastic Search php

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I'm using the Elastic Search php client ([this one](https://packagist.org/packages/elasticsearch/elasticsearch)). I'm trying to get the total number of documents in a type, but can't figure out how to do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's what I've tried:

```
$params['index'] = $index_name;
$params['type'] = 'applicant';
$applicants_count = Es::count($params)["count"];
```

But that always seems to return 0.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. This happened because I was trying to get the result in my test, which called count to soon after the document was indexed. I added the `refresh` command in between (`Es::indices()->refresh(array("index" => $params["index"]));`) and that solved the problem:

```
$params['index'] = $index_name;
$params['type'] = 'applicant';
Es::indices()->refresh(array("index" => $params["index"]));
$applicants_count = Es::count($params)["count"];
```